# Substitution with differential equations (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Using the subsitution $u(x)=y^3$, solve the differential equation $$y^2\cdot\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)+\frac{y^3}x=\frac2{x^2} \quad (x>0)$$

So in starting this, $u=y^3$

$u^{1/3}=y$

Next, I substituted and got,

$$u^{2/3} \left( \frac{du^{1/3}}{dx}\right)=\frac2{x^2}-\frac ux$$

$$ \frac{du^{1/3}}{dx}= \frac{2}{ x^2u^{2/3}}-\frac{u^{1/3}}x$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}= \frac{2u^{7/3}}{x^2}-\frac ux$$

I am not sure if i am right or not? Does it look like im on the right track or did i make an error somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way of proceeding: By the power rule,

$$y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{d}{dx} y^3 = \frac{1}{3} \frac{du}{dx}$$

So your equation can be written as

$$\frac 1 3 u'(x) + \frac{u(x)}{x} = \frac{2}{x^2}$$

This is linear.

Comment: did you get y=3x^-1/3+Cx^-1/3

Comment: I mean y=3x^(-1/3)+c^-x

Comment: @user104922 Not quite. There don't seem to be any $x^{1/3}$ in the solution.